# Azure web app for containers with azure file share

Tags: docker-container, docker-for-windows, azure-files, azure-storage-files, azure-web-app-for-containers

In azure portal, I have deployed a windows docker container with a .net core website in it. Then configured a web app for containers. 
All good until I tried to add a path mapping ( volume mount). There are ui options to do it but  they doesnt work. I can see a file share mount but can not write/read to it within container ( kudu). And dignostic logs on azure portal says, invalid volume specified.

Does it suppose to work this way i.e does azure file share works with web app for containers? Busy trying many things but no success.

Are there other ways to mount/map a azure file share?

In my search what I found so far is:

1. Bring your storage, web app for containers is only in public preview for linux only
2. MS declined to bring azure file share to web app for containers ( because there are orher options, which options??!!)
3. Azure container instance has possibility to add azure file share mount.

As I have seen options to do it portal, I am lost here about what is true. My .net core webapp has nlog logging, which is the first reason to make a file share which will be used for logging.

Answer (score 0):

Azure File share is actually supported in docker for both Windows and Linux. I'd recommend checking the following official documentation on [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/persistent-data-volumes/), but you might have to configure your web app to connect to it. Let me know if this helps.